# How Kubernetes determines which pool will be deployed the pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 pools, how Kubernetes determines which pool will be deployed the pods?

I am asking because sometimes Kubernetes deploy all sets of pods into a pool there is no resource available and the other pool has enough resources

In the practice, Kubernetes (from GKE) are getting the wrong node pool, with fewer resources, and because of that, many times the deployment fails. And I have to cordon the node and restart the deployment to deploy to a free node pool

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes scheduler picks the the right node to schedule your container based on the resource requests ( cpu & memory request) specified in your deployment specs.

Comment: In theory. In the practice, Kubernetes (from GKE) are getting the wrong node pool, with fewer resources, and because of that, many times the deployment fails. And I have to cordon the node and restart the deployment to deploy to a free node pool

Comment: Not in theory in practical as well, if your deployment spec specifies limits only or don’t specify any request specs then pods are scheduled on best effort nodes.

Comment: It is not what I experienced in the practice, GKE/Kubernetes is selecting the node pool with fewer resources and falling into creating new pods. I manage a cluster with more than 900 pods

Comment: Oh that’s node good then .. how about using taints & tolerations or node affinity  . Is that option for you .